# Set a button used for routing to 'active' for starting route

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-ui-router, angular-material2

I have a new project using `angular/material`.  I am trying to setup the toolbar/nav using buttons.  I need to have the starting active route's button set to `active with focus`.

The routes are dynamically generated from the routing module. A route entry looks like:

```
{
path: "route-two",
component: RouteTwoComponent,
data: {
  isTab: true,
  tabName: "This is the Second one",
  tabHint: "This is a hint"
}
```

}

The `default/starting` route is set like this:

```
{
  path: "",
  redirectTo: StartTab,
  pathMatch: "full",
  data: { isTab: false }
},
{ path: "**", redirectTo: "", data: { isTab: false } }
```

`StartTab` is imported from a set of project constants:

```
import { StartTab } from "../constants";
```

Here is a shot of the starting state showing the active route.  Note no active buttons:
[image]

Here is what is should look like when starting:

[image]

Any suggestions?

See the Stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-routing?file=src/app/app.component.html).

Thanks as always.

Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the **routerLinkActive** property to set the active style.

```
    <button
  mat-tab-link
  *ngFor="let tabItem of knownRoutes"
  mat-raised-button
  [routerLink]="[tabItem.path]"
  routerLinkActive="active-link" 
  [matTooltip]="tabItem.data.tabHint"
>
  {{tabItem.data.tabName}}
</button>
```

and the css class active-link

```
.active-link {
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

If you want the white color, you have to set opacity to 1 since your mat-tab-link attribute applies a style with opacity 0.6.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-routing-iw5wp3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Thank you for the quick response - your solution works as indicated. A follow up question - Since this is material, how would you approach this to provide a theme independent solution?  If a different theme where chosen, the back-ground color of the button when it has focus may be different.

Comment: To answer my own question, simply make the `class = .active-link { opacity: 1; }`   The `background-color` is not needed.